# Debug Iphone Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: iphone, debugging

My iphone app randomly received this message. I know certain it is memory release problem. However what is the best way to find which object leads this problem. Here are what I have tried

1. Use Instrument Leak and
   ObjectAllocation Trace. Dont saw any
   help to know which object have this
   problem

   2. Put NSZombieEnabled=YES and project executive ... Dont saw any
      help either
   3. Put NSLog everywhere but the EXE_BAD_ACCESS just appear anywhere.
      in the debuger, just saw the code
      happened in the assembly. like
      objc-msg send.
   4. review code many times and read memory management a lot time
      and research online a lot time. but
      no surprise.

   Is there a completed solution to figure out this problem easily. I am a previous Visual C++ programmer, I deal with memory management with years and it is easy to debug and figure out in Visual C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093919/what-is-the-most-hated-error-you-have-encounter-when-developing-for-the-iphone

Comment: @frostbyt2k: aaahh!! infinite loop! I am trapped in hyperlink recursion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Juan noted, the first stop is the Debugger - what does the debug window give for a stack trace when the app crashes?  You should be able to see the line it crashed on... you said in a comment to one response that you saw the crash happen around the lines:

```
CGPDFDocumnetRef docA=CGPDFDocumentCreatWithURL(myurl);
CGPDFDocumnetRef docB=CGPDFDocumentCreatWithURL(myurl);
```

Are you really using the same URL object for both calls?  Which line is it exactly?

It could be something around the way you make use of the CGPDFDocumentRef, you can find example code how Apple uses them in the QuartzDemo project, file "QuartzImageDrawing.m" (you can find the demo project from the developer portal or embedded in the iPhone documentation with XCode).

XCode is actually pretty powerful, but it does things differently from other IDE's.

Comment: Thanks, Here is the stack looks like in debugger
objc_msgSend.  Error happened here:I never manually call this method.what is this
CFStringGetLength
_CFString...

MyMethod: which i can understand

Comment: If you see a crash in msgSend, it usually means you are sending a message to an object that has been released.

The CFStringGetLength part means that it was trying to ask a string what the length of the string was - but that string is gone, the memory for it released but you are still using the variable that was referring to it.
When you click on the MyMethod line in the stack trace, you should see the exact line of code that caused the crash.  What is that line?

Comment: YOU are absolutely right, finally figure it out because I write some code like this NSLog("Memory warning"). How stupid I am!. Here is objc_msgSend article: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html
Wish everybody never goto that far.

Answer (score 2):

If you couldn't see any helpful debug info, I would suggest you find all the places that you are doing a `release`.  It is most likely the case that you have released something that did not need to be released.  Code would help us in tracing the issue with you.

Comment: Thanks. I just try this code(not actually like this) then found the problem appear repeatly

CGPDFDocumnetRef docA=CGPDFDocumentCreatWithURL(myurl);
CGPDFDocumnetRef docB=CGPDFDocumentCreatWithURL(myurl);

I put these 2 lines code in some other projects, no problem at all. but in this project, it will happen. So, i think it is not pdf doc problem.

Is there a way the system-OS let us know which object or memory address which OS try to release have this problem. look for every object i tried release is painful, because too much and some involve multiple thread.

Comment: Well, look at where you are releasing that one object. It might be happening in various places, depending on how you are storing it, passing it around, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Erich answer, I'd want to add go backward. Start with the most recently added release and work from there.

I ran in to this and it turned out I was releasing an **auto-released object** that was **returned** from a **convenience method** built in to the Cocoa-Touch framework. My problem was as Erich described -- I released this auto-released object. When the system attempted to release it, the program gave the error you are describing.

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Good suggestion. That usually is the fastest way to track it. I did the same thing in my own code.  I am still getting used to the objective-c way of handling it (relatively easy, honestly, but just gotta get used to it).

Comment: i am checking review my code base on this way right now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know what happend is using the xCode Debbuger, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will also receive the message when you don't pass enough parameters to a variable argument method.  For example having a NSLog statement like this:    NSLog(@"Hello %@");

Answer (score 0):

To check what the error might be

Use NSZombieEnabled.

To activate the NSZombieEnabled facility in your application:

Choose Project > Edit Active Executable to open the executable Info window.
Click Arguments.
Click the add (+) button in the “Variables to be set in the environment” section.
Enter NSZombieEnabled in the Name column and YES in the Value column.
Make sure that the checkmark for the NSZombieEnabled entry is selected.

found this on iPhoneSDK