# What is the most hated error you have encounter when developing for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ever language has their famous and painfull errors. I will be fun to learn which errors earn this reputation when developing for the iPhone.

Please list yours!

I agree with [GenericTypeTea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44269/generictypetea) 
If you can please list the error code/message and the cause to make for a more useful post.

Comment: How about listing the error code/message and the cause? Might make for a more useful post.

Comment: I like real questions. Not those subjective questions that should not be asked (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/faq)...

Comment: @Burkhard: I do agree. I wonder what purpose these questions have. Do they help anyone to program better? Do they solve a problem? Probably, they only serve to ask a question and maybe gain a few Reps.

Comment: I like real questions too. However after struggling for hours it is nice to connect with a community that shares your pain and pleasure.

Comment: It would be nice if we had a separate place on stackoverflow.com to connect with the community.

Comment: It would be way more useful (and more in the spirit of SO), if a cause/solution to the error message is provided. Why not reformulate the question as suggested by GenericTypeTea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I particularly hate this error.

> Thank you for submitting [application
>   name here] to the App Store. We've
>   reviewed the application and,
>   consistent with the criteria in our
>   approval process, we have chosen not
>   to publish this application. As you
>   know Apple reserves the right, in its
>   sole discretion, to reject an
>   application for any reason.

Comment: This error never occurred to me. Nevertheless +1 because I'm so afraid of it.

Answer (score 8):

Any error that has to do with code signing.

Comment: This has improved in xcode 3.1.3, but I hate the amount of time I lose per day waiting for code signing.

Answer (score 6):

I hate all the device sync errors like

"iTunes could not connect to iPhone because an unknown error occurred (0xE8000025)"

Oh the humanity.

Answer (score 5):

I hate this one
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (sometimes called EXEC_BAD_ACCESS)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093916/debug-iphone-program-received-signal-excbadaccess

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the most frustrating error is actually the error that **never happens**.  E.g. when you have an `IBOutlet` that has not been properly "plugged in", rather then getting a `NullPointerException` or some such, the code just silently does nothing.  Why does sending a message to a "null" object not throw an exception?  Grr....

Comment: Because the gain you get from not having to check for nil values everywhere (see: Java) is far vaster than the occasional misstep you get from having a message go to a nil object when you were expecting an object to be present.

In consumer application development, code that keeps running is always preferred to code that crashes...

Comment: I could not disagree more.  My development time is far more precious than the few nanoseconds it takes the JVM to detect a null reference.

Comment: Of course, it's Objective-C (more so than a JVM) that's taking the few extra nanoseconds to detect nils in order to special case that situation.

Comment: Not having to check for nils everywhere saves a tremendous amount of code and development time.  If you truly want to guarantee that your IBOutlets are connected, I've found that using assert(yourOutlet != nil) for each outlet within awakeFromNib or similar does a good job of testing these.

Comment: I save way more developer time not having to check for nil, and to make use of that ability to intelligently write code that relies on passing messages to nil being OK, than I ever would from having an accidental nil reference cause an issue.  Remember that Objective-C is at the core a message passing language, and not really C.  I've been writing apps for the iPhone full time for over a year now and I have only had an object being nil cause an issue TWICE and both times were simple UI issues where something failed to show or an action failed to trigger, which I fixed in about a minute.

Comment: @Brad Larson- OK, so to detect whether my outlets are connected I have to write extra code... fine, but this "saves a tremendous amount of code" how?  I know this is just a fundamental difference between a ObjC and Java-like languages.  I understand where you are coming from, but I prefer the system to detect such situations as programming errors, and fail appropriately.  I much prefer the system to fail and stop, than to continue on pretending that everything is fine, when in fact it is not.  That's part of the normal debugging process you must do before you release your code.

Comment: @CaffeineComa Totally agreed with your point. If for-example I am saving something in some database, but some values are null/nil by mistake, then it is much better for the application to throw a null pointer exception rather than corrupting the database completely over the period of time. And in real world too, when you don't raise what problems you are having, the chances are less that the problems get solved.

Answer (score 2):

Sending `autorelease` to an object you do not own, the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and you have no clue when did the object get released.

Answer (score 1):

My most-hated error is when you download sample code to check something out, go to run it, and realize it's set to run on the device when you haven't changed the bundle identifier and the code isn't signed.

Answer (score 0):

I despise the error about "gcc exited with status code 1" and no other information.

Answer (score 0):

I love it and hate it that you can send messages to nil objects. I love it because you don't have to check for nil everywhere. I hate it because sometimes you're looking for that error for hours when all you do is send a message to a nil object. In that case an error would have been nice